# when I'm try to download video using pytube but its not woking

Tags: python, pytube

Unable to download video using pytube

```
import customtkinter
from pytube import YouTube

def startDownload():
    try:
        ytLink = link.get()
        YouTube(ytLink).streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
    except:
        print("YouTube link is invalid")
    print("Download Complete!")

#Link input
url_var = tkinter.StringVar()
link = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, width=400, height=40, textvariable=url_var)
link.pack()

#Download button
download = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="Download", command=startDownload)
download.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
```

error in Line number 6.                                           input take but download function not work
output - YouTube link is invalid
Download Complete!

Comment: What is the output this produces? Since your part of the code is rather trivial while the rest in `pytube` may be much morke complex, it could also be there. Have you checked the according bugtracker? Also, generally, make sure you provide a [mcve], so if it happens in line 6, lines 7 and further are not relevant. That said, you have a catch-it-all `except` where you actively discard any error info apart from the fact that one happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pytube import Youtube
```

That's because you are downloading the first one of the available streams which is usually 720p. To download a 360p resolution stream, you can do:

```
YouTube('https://youtu.be/2lAe1cqCOXo').streams.filter(res="360p").first().download()
```

Note: this is *YouTube*, not Youtube.

**Short explanation:** You need to use *filter()* to choose a specific resolution you want to download. For example, if you call:

```
yt = YouTube('https://youtu.be/2lAe1cqCOXo')
```

it returns the available stream to *yt*. You can view all the streams by typing:

```
yt.streams
```

You can filter which type of filter you want. To filter only 360p streams you can write:

```
yt.streams.filter(res="360p")
```

To filter only 360p streams and download the first one type this:

```
yt.streams.filter(res="360p").first().download()
```

Comment: not working bro :(